# couchbase mock with nodejs sdk 3.0

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchbase-nodejs-sdk

Ths is a newbie question, there seems to be documentation in previous versions of the nodejs SDK on using `couchbase.Mock` does this exist in 3? How do I set it up?

What I tried:
I tried setting up like in the docs [here](https://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-node-client-2.1.4/) but I get:

```
 make test
make: *** No rule to make target `test'.  Stop.
```